# Signalr Issue on Azure Service Fabric: Error during WebSocket handshake

Tags: azure, signalr, azure-service-fabric

We are using Service Fabric for hosting our messaging service ASP.NET Core web API (**leveraging signalr**) and React web application as a client.  Everything works exactly as expected on local machines but not on Azure.  We have configured CORS policies for cross-origin handling since the service and the web app are hosted on different servers. Configured sticky sessions in load balancer. This CORS Policy works in local machine with the service and client hosted on different ports.

Post hosting the application on Azure, I get an Error in the browser console as

> Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500

[image]

Comment: The fact you are getting an HTTP 500 means there is an likely an unhandled exception happening in your code at the server level. Check the logs if you have any or just run the app in debug and try to see what is going on

Answer (score 0):

The issue is very likely to be happening because of CORS.

Looking the screenshot you provided, it is possible to see the CORS exception and, as you are aware, the front-end application calling the SignalR service are hosted on different locations(The domain is the same but different ports).

The CORS settings you applied probably didn't work.

You have two solutions:

- Configure [CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2) in the ASP.NET CORE, so SignalR can accept the call from other domains.
- Host both on same domain + port to avoid CORS

Comment: I already configured CORS to enable calls from other domain; issue still persist. I tried publishing same service as appservice , it worked. But , problem is with service fabric based hosting. Hosting service and client on the same domain+port is not an option at this moment.

Comment: Probably is because it is running behind the Reverse Proxy, Try to expose the SignalR service direct then, like you did for the FE.

Comment: Further while trying out other options - it works when hosted as app service and as single node service fabric cluster ,  used a custom port and configured load balancer for that port with client ip session persistence.  It works. But , issues is with multi node service fabric cluster using same configurations (used for working single node setup).

Comment: Given it works when exposed directly, we can confirm the problem was the reverse proxy, It work with single node because the load balancer knows only one node, on multiple nodes the load balancer send the traffic to every node of that node type in a round robin approach, in this case, you application must be running on all nodes of same node type to work properly.

Comment: Finally it worked, added placement-constraint in manifest along with nodetypename, Thanks @Diego Mendes for your help.